# Rails output polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations, pg-search

I want to implement a search functionality in my Rails app by using the pg_search gem. I've set up everything like it says in the [documentation](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search). Then I've set up a search **controller** with a show action:

```
def show
  @pg_search_documents = PgSearch.multisearch(search_params)
end
```

The search itself works but I have a really annoying problem in my view. Whatever I do, it always outputs an array of PgSearch::Document objects. Even when I only write this in my **view**:

```
<%= @pg_search_documents.each do |document| %>
<% end %>
```

I get this (I've shortened it):

```
[#<PgSearch::Document id: 2, content: "…", searchable_id: 28, searchable_type: "Vessel">, #<PgSearch::Document id: 3, content: "…", searchable_id: 27, searchable_type: "Vessel">]
```

I know that pg_search sets up a **polymorphic association** which I've never dealt with before — could that be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've accepted Todd's answer though the one from @blelump was correct, too. I'm sorry but I had to pick one.

Comment: Thanks! If it's any consolation to @blelump, I've voted up his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= @pg_search_documents.each do |document| %>
<% end %>
```

This is a classic error, one I remember being puzzled over when I first started learning Rails. The mistake is using `<%= %>` with `each`. The return value of `each` is the array that you're iterating over (in this case, `@pg_search_documents`), and by using `<%=`, you're telling Rails to create a string from that array and insert it into your view. That generally isn't what you want: you want the view to be generated by the code inside the block you're passing to `each`.

Use `<% @pg_search_documents.each do |document| %>` instead (omitting the `=`) and you'll avoid the dump of the array's content.

You may also need to use `.searchable` as @blelump suggests, but I wanted to answer the other half of your question, as it's a common pitfall.

Answer (score 1):

To get back to the original source model, `searchable` call is needed on these search result records, e.g:

```
<% @pg_search_documents.each do |document| %>
  <%= document.searchable %>
<% end %>
```

You can also switch back to the source model within your controller, e.g:

```
@pg_search_documents = PgSearch.multisearch(search_params).collect(&:searchable)
```

Then, the `@pg_search_documents` will contain `Vessel` elements.